# índice array boolean

Tags: booleano

Tengo un array boolean con true y false (validPos[])y una variable que me indica el nº de "true" en el array (posiciones). ¿Como hago un bucle que recorra el array pero solo por las posiciones "true", es decir que se salte las "false"?

```
if (posiciones<validPos.length){
            for(int i=0;i<posiciones;i++)
              while(validPos[i]){
                    ...
                    }
                
               }
                 

            }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Pues.. creas otro array que diga las posiciones que son true, y recorres ese array y usas esos indices para acceder al original. No, no hay una instruccion magica que lo haga...

Comment: Solo te equivocaste del condición, pon "!" antes de validPos, y una algo que evite que i llegue hasta el limite del arreglo. while(!validPos[i++] && i<posicines);